# Set Status Detail on Apex Jobs page

Tags: queueable-interface

When using the Queueable interface, is there a way to set the Status Detail on the Apex Jobs page?  Seems like that field is only for catching the errors, but it would be nice to be able to insert some text there if the job completed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. This is a system managed field that cannot be manipulated by developers. If you throw an error, then the transaction is rolled back, and the error appears in the field. Otherwise, the field shows Success, and you cannot modify this value.